# What episodes/quotes are references in Doctor Who Season 10 finale?

Tags: doctor-who

Heavy spoilers for those who didn't see the last episode of Season 10.

During this episode

> The Doctor is fighting not to regenerate.

We can see that in the end of the episode, but also in the middle.

But at then end of the episode

> The Doctor quotes number 10 and number 11 regeneration phrases : "I don't wanna go" and "Remember when the doctor was me".

But moreover we learn afterwards that

> One of the earlier quotes was actually from his first incarnation : "The Original you might say".

This realisation makes me think that

> the impending regeneration is blurring the lines between number 12 and previous Doctors, thus leading to these quotes resurfacing.

But this might be the case during all of the episode. And not only in the end.

My question is : Are there any other direct quotes from previous incarnations of the doctor in this episode ?

> PS : I willingly did not use the tag "regeneration" since the question title mentions the episode. The tag should be here, but would create a spoiler.

Comment: At one point he offers a girl a Jelly Baby, referencing the 4th (Tom Baker).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There aren't loads of direct quotes but there are plenty of references.

For example, there's a lovely preamble from the Master early in the episode when he says "Ugh, **Grandad**'s back" referencing the first Doctor and his granddaughter Susan. But I don't think that's a direct quote from any previous incarnation.

"Nothing wrong with kind. **Jelly baby?**" - a fourth Doctor reference but Capaldi has whipped these out before on the Orient Express.

Bill says "**I don't want to live if I can't be me anymore**. Do you understand?" and the Doctor says "Yeah." reflecting the Doctor's own regeneration issues from this and similar feelings from previous incarnations.

"**Where there's tears, there's hope.**" - referencing the Third Doctor: "A tear, Sarah Jane? No, don't cry. While there's life, there's hope." -himself referencing Cicero and also referencing Heather's tears.

"**It's the scarecrows!**" reference to the Tenth  Doctor story "The Family of Blood" and a very similar siege at the farm reflecting the siege at the school.

"**Telos. Sealed you in your ice tombs. Voga. Canary Wharf. Planet 14**" - direct references to previous Cyberman encounters.

Just after being blasted by Bill, "**Hello. I'm the Doctor**" - I hear this in Tom Baker's voice but every incarnation says it.

"**I'm not a doctor. I am THE Doctor. The original, you might say**" refers to the First Doctor line from the Five Doctors and repeated at the end of this episode by the First Doctor (although technically the third actor incarnation of the first Doctor incarnation - LOL).

I'll mention the "**Time enough**" line uttered as as the Doctor subdues his regeneration and prepares to die but that is a Roy Batty (Blade Runner) reference.

“**Sontarans! perverting the course of human history!**" from Fourth Doctors first line (*Robot* 1974) but Capaldi has said that before in *"Listen"*

"**I don't want to go**" - 10th Doctor quote/

"**when the Doctor was me.**" is a partial 11th Doctor quote was "I will always remember when the Doctor was me."

Comment: I had not spotted the Roy Batty reference. I should watch Blade Runner again

Comment: @Edelk - I was having real trouble believing that the Doctor wanted to just die until he said that.

Comment: You can also mention that "The original, you might say" was originally spoken by the second actor incarnation of the first Doctor incarnation.

Comment: Additional reference - floor 507 is a hat tip to Russell T Davies, who would regularly use the number 57 (50+7") to refer to "a fairly large but random number".

The line about "THE Doctor" was first used in another form in Robot - "You are A Doctor, but I am THE Doctor - the definite article, you might say".

Answer (score 1):

- At one point he offers a girl a Jelly Baby, referencing the 4th doctor (e.g. as in *Face of Evil*)
- "The original, you might say" is actually from the 1st doctor in *The Five Doctors*
- Triggering ground explosions with the sonic may be an homage to 3rd doctor serial *The Sea Devils*.
- Many previous Cyberman stories are also mentioned, including 2nd doctor serial *Tomb of the Cybermen*

Answer (score 0):

When he is lying unconscious at the end of the episode, he looked like 3rd Doctor Jon Pertwee with his white head of hair, puffed sleeves and red-lined cloak.

Comment: Any photo you can provide? Maybe a comparison?